# Расширение mysqli не найдено

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

> phpmyadmin не работает     apache
> 2.4,  mysql 5.5, php 5.4.9, winddows 7    php.ini extension_dir = 
> "C:\apche24\php\ext" 
> extension=php_mysql.dll 
> extension=php_mysqli.dll все это 
> раскомментируемо и указано правильно
>
> при запуске phpinfo() load
> configuration file file (php.ini) Path
> - C:/windows/  Loaded Configuration File - none (должно видеть php.ini) 
> что и где нужно исправить?

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в Переменные среды -> path: "C:\apche24\php"  и "C:\apche24\php\ext"

Comment: проблема решилась по другому

Comment: каким образом?

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Comment: каким образом sudo должно работать на Windows ???

Comment: А здесь этот ответ точно не работает, выше сказано почему. Предлагаю удалить, вы даже специальный знак получите за это )